# How to create an Array inside ActiveModel::EachValidator

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Ruby-on-Rails 4. I have created a custom validator but cannot assign value to an array. It shows error 
undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass`. 
It highlights  `@msg << 1`

For instance, my model is like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_secure_password
    validates :email,:email_format => true, :on => :create
    validates :password, password_format:{with: "upercase"}
end
```

My custom validator

```
class PasswordFormatValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  #def initilize(options)-Fixed
  def initialize(options)
  @msg=[]
  @password1 = options[:attributes=>[:password]]
  @val=options.inspect
  super
  end

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
   record.errors[attribute] << @val

    unless (value.nil? || value.empty?)
    @msg << 1
    #record.errors[attribute] << "testing"

    end

 end

end
```

@val output

```
{:attributes=>[:password], :complexity=>3, :length=>6, :class=>User(id: integer, email: string, password_digest: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your constructor name, it should be `initialize` and not `initilize`. This is why your `@msg` variable is undefined - your constructor has never been called!

Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks. I was so confused! :)

Comment: Also, not sure how to get the password inside initialize. I have updated my post, please check the @val line. Any idea?

Comment: yes, I can get it inside validate_each(record, attribute, value). But, I was wondering can I get it during initialization?

Comment: I guess, no. Why do you need it there?

Comment: Just wanted to assign all value under initialize. If possible!

Comment: No, it doesn't work this way, you have access only to options there. Look at some existing validators to get the idea how it's done.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Really appreciate your help. :)